# Creating a list from values taken from a text file.

Tags: python, list, sorting, readline

I am creating a sort and I need a list of integers which will be taken from a text file. How can I feed data from a text file into a list of of integers. it is just one int on every line of the text file. My guess was just make an empty list and say `list.append(int(f.readline))` but I am not sure. There is no actual code because I wanted understand this logic first.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all lines with `file.readlines()` and then iterate over them easily.

Try this:

```
filename = "PATH TO YOUR FILE"
result = []
with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        result.append(int(line))

# If you want your list sorted, uncomment the following line
#result.sort()
```

Comment: Just want to make sure, a for each loop terminates when it reaches the end of the file correct?

Comment: readlines returns a list with all the lines of the file, the for loop will iterate over each of them till the last one.

Comment: The preferred file handling when you just want to read once through the file is to do "for line in fp:" as opposed to "for line in fp.readlines():" - no dummy list is created, you just iterate over the file a line at a time. And yes, this for loop will terminate when it reaches the end of the file.